# I can't find drives that are already mounted

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

First I created 2 new partition tables with gparted each one for my two drives.
Following this I ran `sudo mkdir /hdd` as well as `sudo mkdir /ssd`.
Afterwards I ran `sudo vim /etc/fstab` and added two new lines of code.

```
/dev/sdb1    /hdd    ext4    defaults    0    0
/dev/sdc1    /ssd    ext4    defaults    0    0
```

At last after I saved vim I mounted both of them.

```
sudo mount /hdd
sudo mount /ssd
```

I checked with gparted and saw that both drives where mounted at the right point so now I looked into my files and didnt find any of them.
So what can I do to fix this?

As I see there is confusion I will specify my problem.

[image: A picture of where I thought mounted drives would be displayed]

My question is why after I mounted the drives aren't there the drives.

There should be three drives but there is only one which is my installation medium for ubuntu.

Comment: it wasn't about the files that I was expecting to find but the drives themself. I can't find the drives and a way to open them even though after I mounted them they should be accessible to me.

Comment: How did you create the partition tables? Creating partition tables will not create partitions. Did you create partitions? New partitions will not have files, so I don't understand why you are missing your files. Which files are you missing?

Comment: @subject050000, Please edit your question to show also what is displayed by the terminal command `df`.

Comment: +1 to mook's advice. I would add that you should specify the partitions by the UUID of the file systems instead of `/dev/sdb1` etc, because those device addresses are allocated automatically and may change without warning, while the UUIDs are stable (until you create a new file system).

Comment: @subject050000 I converted my last comment into an answer since it solved your problem. Please don't forget to [accept this answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see the contents of this partitions when you browse to the mountpoint (`/ssd`, `/hdd`) in your filemanager.

If you want the filemanager to show this partitions as drives like in your picture, mount them in subdirectories of `/media`, for example `/media/ssd`, `/media/hdd`.